# Switch/Case on a Type/Class instance?

Tags: actionscript-3, switch-statement

I have a set of different MovieClips:

```
Pink
Yellow
Red
```

and I create an item

```
item = new Pink();
item = new Red();
```

etc...

How do I write a switch case to see which MovieClip I have?

```
switch (item) {
 case Pink:
 // do something
 break;

 case Red:
 // do something
 break;
}
```

i only know how to write switch cases for Strings...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the class name as a string and do a switch on that as you normally would using this method...

```
switch (getQualifiedClassName(item)) {
 case "Pink":
 // do something
 break;

 case "Red":
 // do something
 break;
}
```

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getQualifiedClassName()

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer: don't.

`Pink` and `Red` are both `Color`s so make `Color` have a function:

```
interface IColor
{
  public function doSomething():void;
}
```

and have `Pink` and `Red` extend the function:

```
class Pink extends MovieClip implements IColor
{
  ...
  public override function doSomething():void
  {
    //different code
  }
}

class Red extends MovieClip implements IColor
{
  ...
  public override function doSomething():void
  {
    //more different code
  }
}
```

then in your code you can just call:

```
item.doSomething();
```

and it will do the right thing for either case.

Comment: Seems like a good idea, but I am only toggling the visibility of MovieClips in this case...will note this for the future.

Comment: Sometimes I'm dealing with classes I have no control over, or with mix of objects, structures and even methods in one logic block (for example: `if(object.hasSomething()) {} else if(method_call()) {} else if($precomputed_expensive_boolean_value) {}`. In those cases I can't just add doSomething() to parent class and override them in child classes. In addition, sometimes it's just not responsibility of those classes to handle whatever I'm trying to do in `case` statements. I hate stacks of `if`'s and switch(true) is easier to read and follow.

Comment: stacks of `if` statements are fine, but `switch(true)` is not.

Answer (score 3):

There's already an answer for this question but for anyone who is interested you can also do this:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var cat:Cat = new Cat();

            switch(Class(Object(cat).constructor))
            {
                case Cat : trace("instance of " + Cat); break;
                case Dog : trace("instance of " + Dog); break;

            }// end switch

            // output: 

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

internal class Cat
{ 
    public function Cat() { }

}// end class

internal class Dog
{ 
    public function Dog() { }

}// end class
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the “is” keyword:

```
if (item is Pink) // do something
```

Using “is” in a case statement would look like this:

```
switch(true)
{
    case item is Pink :
        // do something
        break;

    case item is Red :
        // do something
        break;
}
```

The powerful thing about the “is” statement is that works for inherited types. So, for instance, if I wanted to check for a MovieClip, a Sprite or a SimpleButton, I could just write:

```
if (item is DisplayObject) // do something
```

Since all these types inherit from DisplayObject.

Another benefit is that there is no unnecessary introspection (such as with getQualifiedClassName). Thus, the “is” keyword has far better performance and requires no additional code.

Comment: `switch (true)` statements are awful, don't ever use them.

Comment: @zzzzBov Can you elaborate?

Comment: @lucek, `switch(true)` statements use more characters than necessary to perform identical functionality to `if..else if..else` blocks, are less readable than `if..else if` which makes them less maintainable. It would be easy to accidentally forget a `break` clause and end up with the implicit fallthrough behavior. My advice: don't ever use them.